# Angular ui-grid tables scrolling sideways

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I noticed a strange behavior when scrolling over an angular-ui table, let's take as an example the table displayed on http://ui-grid.info/, this is the normal table:
[image: Normal table]

and this is the same table that slides sideways when scrolling with the mouse (it happens only if the mouse is capable of lateral scrolling):

[image: Table scrolled sideways]

Disabling scrollbars doesn't seem to work. Is there a solution to avoid this behavior?

Comment: lets first get a mouse capable of lateral scrolling :)

Comment: 7 days ago code was merged in on their github that changes width calculations.  I haven't tested the code, but if you build their latest code from github that might resolve it.

Comment: The issue seems to be fixed now, thank you Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Rob Louie, the code has now been fixed: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/commit/f68c5ee47415a48f2f6bd54781774714b03941c2